# _renderNode is not a function in ember upgraded version to render first and last node of a component

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am upgrading from ember 2.5.0 to 2.18.0 but _renderNode is no more available. Is there any other function to get the same result?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Want to get the first and last node of a component. To fetch details and customize it.

Comment: and why do you want to do this? you can get the html element with `this.element`. for child components you should give data down in the template. if you give more context for your use case we maybe can help you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that we can do to help you out with this process but it will need to start with helping you with some context before we get started.

First of all, there is a convention in EmberJS (and a lot of other javascript libraries & frameworks) that any method that is prefixed with a `_` is considered **private**. This usually means that it should not be used because it will most likely be removed in a future version.

The second thing to note is that Ember has a concept of an LTS release, you can read more about how the LTS process works on [this page](https://www.emberjs.com/blog/2016/02/25/announcing-embers-first-lts.html) on the Ember website.

I would recommend at this stage to do the following:

- Upgrade your app (using [ember-cli-update](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-update)) to each LTS version **one at a time** while making sure you remove all deprecations as you go. Read more about deprecations [here](https://emberjs.com/deprecations/)
- Find any place where you are using private methods (prefixed with a `_`) and remove them

Then you should be able to upgrade without any more hassle. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I am updating from old version and the core functionality relying on private functions. I was just looking for a substitute method so that I can rewrite the functionality.

Comment: @Mudit I would recommend following my steps as I laid out. Don't update further than the next LTS at a time and remove deprecations as they crop up. Also for the record I have not been able to find any documentation for _renderNode so you would need to provide more context as to what you're trying to achieve or at least provide a link to the what function you are actually calling to get more direct answers to your question :)